# Phonegap - CSS Flexbox - div fill up rest of page

Tags: css, html, cordova, flexbox

I have a problem by getting flex boxes right. I have tried the settings [here.](http://demo.agektmr.com/flexbox/). I want that the div with the run-map class fills up the rest of the page, but I just do not get it.

```css
body {
    height:100% !important;
}

html {
}

.box {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: column;
 justify-content: center;
 align-content: stretch;
 align-items: stretch;
}

.box div.header {
 order: 0;
 flex: 0 1 auto;
 align-self: auto;
}

.box div.run-data {
 order: 1;
 flex: 1 1 auto;
 align-self: auto;
 background-color: blue;
}

.box div.run-map {
 order: 2;
 flex: 2 1 auto;
 align-self: auto;
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app" class="box">
           <div class="header">
             <table id="header-table">
              <th onclick="loadContent('main.html')">Home</th>
              <th onclick="loadContent('run.html')">Run</th>
              <th>Statistics</th>
              <th>Settings</th>
              <th>Donate</th>
             </table> 
           </div>
           <div id="content" class="content-box">
            <div class="run-data">
      <script type="text/javascript">onload_run();</script>
      <h1><span id="stopwatch">00:00:00</span></h1>
      <p>Latitude: <span id="latitude"></span></p>
      <p>Longitude: <span id="longitude"></span></p>
      <p>Altitude: <span id="altitude"></span></p>
      <p>Accuracy: <span id="accuracy"></span></p>
      <p>Altitude Accuracy: <span id="altitude-accuracy"></span></p>
      <p>Distance: <span id="distance"></span> km</p>
      <p>Pace: <span id="pace"></span> min/km</p>
      <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="start();">
      <input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="stop();">
      <input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="reset();">
  </div>
  <div class="run-map">
      <script type="text/javascript">
   //Load in the Map right at the beginning
   Map.initialize();
      </script>
  </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I make the last div (run-map) fill up the rest of the page?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the red box to be below or next to the blue box? Here is an example with the red box showing to the right of the blue box.

As a rule for "flex box items that fill the rest of the page", make sure to add `height: 100%` to the `<html>` tag AND the container that holds the item you want to fill up the rest of the page.

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 100%;
}
.box div.header {
  order: 0;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  align-self: auto;
}
.box div.run-data {
  order: 1;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  align-self: auto;
  background-color: blue;
}
.content-box {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
.box div.run-map {
  order: 2;
  flex: 2 1 auto;
  align-self: auto;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app" class="box">
    <div class="header">
      <table id="header-table">
        <th onclick="loadContent('main.html')">Home</th>
        <th onclick="loadContent('run.html')">Run</th>
        <th>Statistics</th>
        <th>Settings</th>
        <th>Donate</th>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="content-box">
      <div class="run-data">
        <script type="text/javascript">
          onload_run();
        </script>
        <h1><span id="stopwatch">00:00:00</span></h1>
        <p>Latitude: <span id="latitude"></span>
        </p>
        <p>Longitude: <span id="longitude"></span>
        </p>
        <p>Altitude: <span id="altitude"></span>
        </p>
        <p>Accuracy: <span id="accuracy"></span>
        </p>
        <p>Altitude Accuracy: <span id="altitude-accuracy"></span>
        </p>
        <p>Distance: <span id="distance"></span> km</p>
        <p>Pace: <span id="pace"></span> min/km</p>
        <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="start();">
        <input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="stop();">
        <input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="reset();">
      </div>
      <div class="run-map">
        <script type="text/javascript">
          //Load in the Map right at the beginning
          Map.initialize();
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```